# Make asynchronous http calls synchronous while displaying progress bar?

Tags: android, http, asynchronous, android-progressbar, synchronous

I want to get json from web service ,displaying progress circle and processing it , then displaying the data. how to make asynchronous calls synchronous without jdts and with loading circle ?Any library or anything else?

For example

```
....some code  
call to json webservice //wait for http call to execute while displaying loading circle  
update the UI
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, one solution is using ProgressDialog, other is ProgressBar, 
ProgressDialog send a Dialog with this progress circle.

for ProgressDialog you should know:

```
progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
progressDialog.setTitle("Downloading JSON ...");
progressDialog.setMessage("Download in progress ...");
progressDialog.setProgressStyle(progressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);//horizontal
progressDialog.setProgressStyle(progressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER); //Circular
progressDialog.setProgress(0);
progressDialog.setMax(20); // the progress has 20 steps
progressDialog.setIndeterminate(true);// infinite loop in the progress
progressDialog.show();
```

for AsyncTask you should know:

**doInBackground()** there is the source code for asynchronous process.

**onProgressUpdate()** there is the source code for you send some pieces to the main thread include UI things. for it works you should use publishProgress() inside doInBackground() method.

**onPostExecute()** this method will be executed after doInBackground finish all the process

**onPreExecute()** this method is for initialize all the things that you need in your asynctask

You can declare and instantiate your ProgressDialog at the beginning on your Activity, then set the **progressDialog.show()** in AsyncTask inside **onPreExecute()**

```
 private class JsonWebService extends AsyncTask<URL, Integer, JSONObject> {
     protected void onPreExecute(){
         progressDialog.show();
     }
     protected JSONObject doInBackground(URL... urls) {
         //here all your code for download your JSON
         //
         //publishProgress(counter);

         return json;
     }

     protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
         setProgressPercent(progress[0]);
     }

     protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject result) {
         //use your JSON as you want your download is finished
         // close your progressdialog
         progressDialog.dismiss();
     }
}
```